# passing without null terminated string to method in java

Tags: java

I am using vr3 speech to text module on Raspberry Pi3. I want to activate the pin output with the voice command I give. Something is wrong in the code block below. If I input `string()` directly to the method `speech2command`, everything looks normal; (speech2command("ONE") ..etc ). If I use speechstring value I have a problem. Maybe I need a null terminated string? If so, how should I add that?

```
private static String toASCII(int value) {

    int length = 4;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        builder.append((char) ((value >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
//******************************************************************************   

public static void speech2command(String strSource) {

    //   System.out.println("--> Comingstring-->"+strSource);      
    if(strSource.equals("ZERO")==true) {
        System.out.println("--> GPIO state-->ZERO STATE");
        output.low();  // LED OFF
    }
    if(strSource.equals("ONE")==true) {
        System.out.println("--> GPIO state-->ONE STATE");
        output.high();  // LED ON
    }    
}

//****************************************************************************
//
//
//

for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                     
    ret[i] = Integer.valueOf(globalstringhex.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2), 
16).byteValue();//Hexstring --> ASCII 
    int k=ret[i];
    if (k>=32 && k<=126) {//input "readable chars"   
        speechstring+= toASCII(k);           
    }                   
}

globalstringhex="";
speech2command(speechstring);//---> This line is not working correctly. 
textArea_4.append("\n\r");

speechcommand("ONE");//---> if i use parameter "ZERO" or "ONE" everything is ok. But if i use 
speechcommand(speechstring); line ,  LED never work.
```

Comment: well what is the value of `speechstring`. Also there is nothing like a null-terminated string in java. String in java and c work a bit differently.

Comment: What does your code mean? Could you format it to have proper spacing and no empty lines? Also point out what is that code expected to do and what it actually does..

Comment: For example, when 65 is passed to the ascii function (toASCII(65) ) , I get the character "A". Then  " speechstring= speechstring +"A" command is being executed. now question ;  speechstring is not equal "A". Why?    command line below  never executes. why?
                                                                                             
                 if(speechstring("A")==true) {
          
          output.low();
         }